# dynamically create more php objects on scroll

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to do the following and do not know how to best approach it:

I have a Facebook like Wall in a Social Website I created.
Every wall Post is a PHP Object with several "comment" objects attached to it.
All Relevant Data is currently fetched from the Database at the time the page loads and works as I wanted it to.

My Wall is getting quite long so I would like to implement infinite scrolling via JQuery and Ajax.
I wanted to send a request for more post objects to a php page which would instantiate them and send the finished objects back. Now I have read that this is bad practice sending PHP Objects via JSON and that it can lead to Problems and potential attack vectors.

How should I approach this? Write the entire wall in Jquery? Have it send Requests for the Data to PHP but display everything with JQuery instead of PHP?

A few pointers would be very appreciated.

Comment: @AlexanderLanganke your question is primarily opinion-based "how should I approach this" and you did not provide any code that you had tried, and I don't find it to be a bad practice to return an object as JSON as long as you are not exposing any data you don't want to.  It will actually reduced the load to your server if you build the html in JS

Answer (score 0):

You should send AJAX request for needed posts and return ready HTML which you can just append to the container with $('wall_container').append($(new_post_html));

Comment: Thank you. That is what I thought you would say

Comment: suggesting that response should be html is simply telling OP what they want to hear. This doesn't suggest why it should be html and not JSON. Frameworks like angular.js wouldn't exist if sending JSON wasn't a reasonable practice

Answer (score 0):

I would say load the initial page and append the data to the wall as you get it. No need to send objects. All the data you need will be in the responseText of the request object

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
var form = new FormData();
form.append('param_1',val_1);
form.append('param_2',val_2);
request.open("http://example.com/getPostsForWall.php","POST",true);
request.send(form);
request.onreadystatechange = function(){
   if(request.status==200 && request.readyState == 4){
        //Successful request
        response = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        //Want to append a title using jquery to your wall that has an id of wall?
        $("#wall").append("<h2 class='wall-post-title'>"+response.post_title+"<h2>");
   }
};
```

This is assuming you have your server side code returning a variable with the key 'post_title' when you send your response